# babel-register not ignoring node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to set up server side rendering for my application (which was bootstrapped using Create React App).

This is what my bootstrap.js looks like

```
require("ignore-styles");

require("babel-register")({
  ignore: [/(node_modules)/],
  presets: ["es2015", "react-app"]
});

require("./index");
```

My index.js looks like this

```
    import express from "express";

// we'll talk about this in a minute:
import serverRenderer from "./middleware/renderer";

const PORT = 3000;
const path = require("path");

// initialize the application and create the routes
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

// root (/) should always serve our server rendered page
router.use("^/$", serverRenderer);

// other static resources should just be served as they are
router.use(
  express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "build"), { maxAge: "30d" })
);

// tell the app to use the above rules
app.use(router);

// start the app
app.listen(PORT, error => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log("something bad happened", error);
  }

  console.log("listening on " + PORT + "...");
});
```

Now when I run my server like this

`NODE_ENV=production node bootstrap.js`

I keep getting errors like this

```
/node_modules/emotion/dist/index.cjs.js:49
  tag.setAttribute('data-emotion', '');
      ^

TypeError: tag.setAttribute is not a function
```

Why is this happening? I thought the node_modules would be ignored when transpiling.

I have no control over what other libraries do, so how can I implement server side rendering if this is the case?

I tried the suggestion in the comment below and I got this error

```
    /node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:328
        throw e;
        ^

Error: Options {"loose":true} passed to /node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/babel-preset-env/lib/index.js which does not accept options.
```

So it looks like there is a transpilation issue...which doesn't make sense, as I'm using CRA, which uses babel anyways to transpile and that works fine.

Comment: have you tried `ignore: ["/(node_modules)/"],` with the quotes, in your first code snippet?

Comment: From documentation https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register.html#ignores-node-modules-by-default it seems it ignores node_modules by default, please try removing the ignore. Or try /\/node_modules\// in ignore

Comment: Hey so, I tried that and I get the error that I've added to the question @Webber

Comment: @RaviTeja no luck there either. Same error.